# Importing a Nunjucks Macro?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, nunjucks

I have a script that renders a nunjucks `contact.html` template that looks like this:

```
    let fs = require('fs');
    let nj = require('nunjucks');
    var contact = fs.readFileSync('./src/contact.html','utf8');
    nj.configure('src');
    let result = nj.render('contact.html');
    console.log(result);
```

It works fine and logs the correct `result`.

I'm trying to add a macro now and I put the definition in a `templates/forms.njk` file.  I then try to load it from `contacts.html` like this:

```
{% import "templates/forms.njk" as forms %}

{% set title = 'Contact' %}
{% extends '_layout.html' %}
{% block content %}
<h1>Test Template</h1>
{% endblock %}
```

Now `results` logs as `null`, but if I remove the macro import will will log the rendered contact template.  Thoughts?

The `src` directory layout looks like this:

```
├── contact.html
├── index.html
├── _layout.html
└── templates
    └── forms.njk
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second macro was missing a closing statement `{% endmacro %}`.  [Sample project here if anyone wants to play with the setup](https://github.com/oleersoy/nunjucks).

Note also updated the `nj.render` call to log the error.

Comment: Hi @LPZ, I updated the question with the directory layout.  I think you are saying that the templates directory should be in the `src` directory and it is.